# Как вызвать метод в другом методе Java..?

Tags: java

Есть метод onClick, в который я хочу поместить другой метод, реализующий intent и apache poi, когда я его [помещаю](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN4o5.png) выдает ошибку. Какие параметры нужно в него передать, чтобы реализовать этот метод в onClick?

```
public void appointButtonClick(View view) {
    readExcelData();
}


public void readExcelData(String ExcelFilePath) {

    // HSSFWorkbook is for .xls
    // XSSFWorkbook is for .xlsx

    String[] path = ExcelFilePath.split(":");

    Workbook workbook = null;

    if (ExcelFilePath.endsWith(".xls")) {

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path[1]));
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("debinf cliinf", "readExcelData: FileNotFoundException " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("debinf cliinf", "readExcelData: Error reading InputStream " + e.getMessage());
        }

    } else if (ExcelFilePath.endsWith(".xlsx")) {

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path[1]));
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("debinf cliinf", "readExcelData: FileNotFoundException " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("debinf cliinf", "readExcelData: Error reading InputStream " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    Log.i("debinf cliinf", "uri is " + ExcelFilePath.endsWith(".xls"));

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Log.i("debinf cliinfo", "sheet is " + sheet);
    if (sheet == null) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Строку.........

Comment: Метод readExcelData ожидает на вход параметр типа String, а вы ничего в него не передаете

Comment: какой параметр в него передать не подскажите по коду? я пока не силен в этом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из названия понятно, что в метод readExcelData()  нужно передать путь к файлу.